# Debugging Verifone E315 POS Sled on xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, point-of-sale, verifone

I'm developing on the Verifone E315 POS for an iOS application and I'm getting tired of unplugging the device and plugging in my iOS device directly to see stack traces.

Does anyone know if it's possible to buy a lightning to micro-USB adapter, plug that into the side of the E315 and debug while my iOS device is docked into the sled?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same requirement, but not payment, only scanning. Do you know any good scanning SDK that will work with the e315 and iPod device?

Comment: Sorry, it's been a few years since I worked on this and the SDK we used was directly from the vendor.

Answer (score 6):

While holding both the scanner buttons plug the micro USB cable into the side of the E315 sled. This will allow you to access your iOS device and read console logs, but the sled will be bypassed and it would be disconnected from your POS application.